# Toggle a class on and off between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="element-1" class="element-show"></div>
   <div id="element-2"></div>
</div>
```

I want class `element-show` to hide from `element-1` and show in `element-2` and vice versa; called from one function in jQuery.

Any way I can do this properly?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I've used `addClass` and `removeClass` in an `if` statement with a `boolean` determining which element is currently active. There's only two elements. But I'd like a possible solution for multiple elements.

Comment: `toggleClass` doesn't really seem to fit considering when `element-1` is toggled with the class, `element-2` should be toggled off ..

Comment: get element using id and add remove class. ref https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp

Comment: Try this : http://freefrontend.com/css-radio-buttons/

Comment: You just `removeClass` from all elements and `addClass` to the one clicked. For a better understanding you should share all relevant code(including what you've tried),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

will something like that be OK?

```js
$("button").on("click", function(e){
  $('.container').children("div").toggleClass("element-show");
})
```

```css
.element-show{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div id="element-1" class="element-show">x</div>
   <div id="element-2">y</div>
</div>
<button>Toggle class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by doing this:

```js
function getClass() {
  var children_container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].children;

  for (var i = 0; i < children_container.length; i++) {
    if ($(children_container[i]).hasClass('element-show')) {
      $(children_container[i]).removeClass();
      if (i == "0") {
        $(children_container[1]).addClass("element-show");
        break;
      } else if (i == "1") {
        $(children_container[0]).addClass("element-show");
        break;
      }
    }
  };
};

getClass();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="element-1" class="element-show"></div>
  <div id="element-2"></div>
</div>
```

If you have more than 2 elements and you want to add the class on rest of them and remove it from the element which already has that class, then you can achieve that by doing this (this function will also work for the case you mentioned too):

```js
function getClass() {
  var children_container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].children;
  var class_elem;
  for (var i = 0; i < children_container.length; i++) {
    if ($(children_container[i]).hasClass('element-show')) {
      class_elem = i;
      $(children_container[i]).removeClass();
      i = 0;
    }
    if (class_elem != undefined) {
      if (i != class_elem) {
        $(children_container[i]).addClass('element-show');
      }
    };
  };
};

getClass();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="element-0"></div>
  <div id="element-1" class="element-show"></div>
  <div id="element-2"></div>
  <div id="element-3"></div>
  <div id="element-4"></div>
</div>
```